# Sort a list within an entity with java 8 Comparators

Tags: java, list, sorting

I want to sort a list within an entity with Java 8 Comparators. 
Can someone help me to replace this here --> thenComparing(???)

```
@Test
public void testSort() {
    // given
    List<Person> values = Lists.newArrayList(
            new Person("you", Lists.newArrayList(new Todo("A"))),
            new Person("me", Lists.newArrayList(new Todo("B"), new Todo("A"), new Todo("C"))),
            new Person("me", Lists.newArrayList(new Todo("A"))),
            new Person("me", Lists.newArrayList(new Todo("D")))
    );

    // when
    List<Person> result = values
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator
                    .comparing(Person::getName))
                    .thenComparing(???) <-- TODO
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // then
    assertEquals(4, result.size());

    Person person_1 = result.get(0);
    assertEquals("me", person_1.getName());
    assertEquals(1, person_1.getTodos().size());
    assertEquals("A", person_1.getTodos().get(0).getName());

    Person person_2 = result.get(1);
    assertEquals("me", person_2.getName());
    assertEquals(3, person_2.getTodos().size());
    assertEquals("A", person_2.getTodos().get(0).getName());
    assertEquals("B", person_2.getTodos().get(1).getName());
    assertEquals("C", person_2.getTodos().get(2).getName());

    Person person_3 = result.get(2);
    assertEquals("me", person_3.getName());
    assertEquals(1, person_3.getTodos().size());
    assertEquals("D", person_3.getTodos().get(0).getName());

    Person person_4 = result.get(3);
    assertEquals("you", person_4.getName());
    assertEquals(1, person_4.getTodos().size());
    assertEquals("A", person_4.getTodos().get(0).getName());

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Todo {

    private String name;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Person {

    private String name;
    private List<Todo> todos;
}
```

Expected sort result: 
Person(name=me, todos=[Todo(name=A)]) 
Person(name=me, todos=[Todo(name=A), Todo(name=B), Todo(name=C)]) 
Person(name=me, todos=[Todo(name=D)]) 
Person(name=you, todos=[Todo(name=A)])

Comment: What framework are `@Data` and `@AllArgsConstructor` from?

Comment: What order do you want? You set an ordering by name is this enough ?

Comment: @markspace Most likely they're Lombok annotations.

Comment: So, you want to sort both the main array *and* all the sub-arrays? I ask, because the 2nd sub-array is `B, A, C` in the code, but `A, B, C` in the expected result. --- Or is the sub-array sorting done in the `Person` constructor?

Comment: Note that `thenComparing` won't sort the sub-array of ToDos — it is used to break ties; it is the second sort key, so when you have two people where `getName()` is "James", `thenComparing` will be used to determine which James comes first.

Answer (score 0):

By editing the classes `Person` and `Todo`, in combination with the fact `String` sorting is built into java this becomes easier.

so lets first think about this, we can use `thenComparing` after the first `comparing` by casting the Todo List to a string, then sorting by that string. we edit the `Person` class first by adding a function that returns the `Todo` list as a string. It will end up looking like:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private List<Todo> todos;

    public Person(String name, List<Todo> todos) {
        this.name = name;
        this.todos = todos;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public List<Todo> getTodos() {
        return todos;
    }

    public String getTodoListAsString() {
        return this.todos.stream()
                .map(Todo::getName)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

We also want to change the `Todo` class to implement Comparable so that we can map the `Todo` list in them into a sorted list. We can accomplish this by editing the `Todo` class as such:

```
public class Todo implements Comparable<Todo> {
    private String name;

    public Todo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Todo o) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(o.getName());
    }
}
```

Now we can use that in the stream as such:

```
List<Person> result = values
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)
                    .thenComparing(Person::getTodoListAsString))
            .map(person -> new Person(person.getName(),
                    person.getTodos()
                            .stream()
                            .sorted()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```